# Null Reference with No trace in Sitecore

Tags: optimization, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I'm currently trying to optimize a clients website, while going through the logs to look for errors, I was faced with multiple

> 8048 00:09:59 ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

messages, but with no Trace data as to where this is happening, does anyone know how to trace these errors or to find out what is causing them?

Comment: The default log4net root logger is set to `INFO` level, try setting it to `DEBUG`. It will provide more info on the calls, but will also slow the site as a result (so not good for PROD)

Comment: Thanks, I'll set it up on our staging site and see what happens

Comment: Add ELMAH - it can be configured through web.config and doesn't interfere with the existing code.  You can have it write to XML files in the App_Data folder (for a short time).  Then you can easily remove it again once you've located your issue.